# How to find out the total number of documents available in my Drive?

Tags: google-drive

How to find out the total number of documents exposed via Google Docs?

Comment: What do you mean by exposed? Do you mean shared with you? Created by you? Opened by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto [script.google.com](http://script.google.com) and start a new script and copy in the following code:

```
function doGet() {  
  Logger.log(DocsList.getAllFiles().length);
}
```

De-bug the code by pressing the "bug" button. An authorization menu will popup, that will ask permission to access Docs.

When having granted the script access to Docs, then play the script by pressing the "play" button. This might take a while, since it must read all files.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to view the logger (menu *views/logs*). Here the amount of files is displayed.

**EDIT**
See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I tried running this script, but it doesn't show me any output.

function doGet() {
Logger.log(DocsList.getAllFiles().length);
}

Comment: @Rpj Did you press the two buttons?

Comment: @Rpj Make sure to press Ctrl + Enter afterwards to show the logger info !!